# Updated string variable from external php file are not being displayed on the html/browser when refreshing content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I recently uploaded a PHP site into my web host, but I do not retrieve new strings, $password2, from an external PHP file. When I run the site locally using MAMP everything works fine. Not sure why the change of behavior if everything seems to be correct when testing locally.
In the HTML part I am using echo $password;. Also, I am using onclick='location.reload();' to reload the page a get a new value from the external PHP file.

```
<?php

include 'includes/password_generator.php';

?>
            <article style="text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(10, 10, 10, 1);" id="legible">
                <center>
                    <h2 class="major">PASSWORD</h2>
                    <h3>Generated Password:
                        <p style="color:yellow;">
                            <?php echo $password2; ?>
                        </p>
                    </h3>
                    <form class="container" action="" method="GET">
                        <input type="submit" onclick='location.reload();' value="submit">
                    </form>
                </center>
            </article>
```

In the PHP file, I am using the function rand() to create random values/strings, etc. I am not sure why this code is not working on the web server from my host

```
function read_dictionary($filename="") {
    //Can use full path or relative path
    $dictionary_file = "data/dictionaries/{$filename}";
    return file($dictionary_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
}

function pick_random($array) {
    $i = rand(0, count($array) -1);
    return $array[$i];
}

function random_symbol(){
$symbols = '!@#$%^&*()';
$i = rand(0, strlen($symbols) -1);
return $symbols[$i];
}

function random_number() {
$numbers = rand(0, 99);
return $numbers;
}

$basic_words = read_dictionary('friendly_words.txt');
$brand_words = read_dictionary('brand_words.txt');

$words = array_merge($brand_words, $basic_words);
//Could Use array_unique()

$password2 = "";
$password2 .= pick_random($words);
$password2 .= random_symbol();
$password2 .= pick_random($words);
$password2 .= random_number();

$password2 = ucfirst($password2);
```

I am a newbie to PHP development, any help would be great!.

Comment: __Debug__ your application. Make sure all functions return what you expect.

Comment: @u_mulder Hello, my script works fine on my local environment. Not sure what else I need to debug. I guess my real question is why my web hosting is having issues to run the script multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I put the code inside an if statement, and from the HTML I changed the method to POST.

HTML:

```
<?php

include 'includes/password_generator.php';

?>
            <article style="text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(10, 10, 10, 1);" id="legible">
                <center>
                    <h2 class="major">PASSWORD</h2>
                    <h3>Generated Password:
                        <p style="color:yellow;">
                            <?php echo $password2; ?>
                        </p>
                    </h3>
                    <form class="container" action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit">
                    </form>
                </center>
            </article>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

function read_dictionary($filename="") {
    //Can use full path or relative path
    $dictionary_file = "data/dictionaries/{$filename}";
    return file($dictionary_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
}

function pick_random($array) {
    $i = rand(0, count($array) -1);
    return $array[$i];
}

function random_symbol(){
$symbols = '!@#$%^&*()';
$i = rand(0, strlen($symbols) -1);
return $symbols[$i];
}

function random_number() {
$numbers = rand(0, 99);
return $numbers;
}

$basic_words = read_dictionary('friendly_words.txt');
$brand_words = read_dictionary('brand_words.txt');

$words = array_merge($brand_words, $basic_words);
//Could Use array_unique()

$password2 = "";
$password2 .= pick_random($words);
$password2 .= random_symbol();
$password2 .= pick_random($words);
$password2 .= random_number();

$password2 = ucfirst($password2);

}
```